# Morphisms in derived category

Tags: abelian-categories, derived-categories

I'm beginning to study abelian and derived categories, and I'm not understand morphisms in derived categories. I understand that morphisms are roofs under an equivalence relationship, but I don´t know how derived category is additive. For example, what is the zero object and zero maps in derived category, what is a direct sum, what is the sum of morphisms? Also, what is an isomorphism in derived category and how should I understant them? I would appreciate an explanation on these concepts.

Also, someone can I give me an example of a morphisms of complexes $f$ such that $H^n(f)=0$ for all $n$ but such that the morphism is not zero in the derived category? Please explain to me how to ensure that the map is not zero in the derived category.

Answer (score 0):

The zero object of the derived category is the zero complex and the direct sum is the direct sum of underlying complexes. If two morphisms can be represented as chain maps you can just add them as chain maps and then apply the functor $\operatorname{Ch}(R) \to D(R)$ to get their sum. This actually describes how to add all maps, since if you have two roofs you can assume the top object (edit: and the qiso out of it) is the same in both and then <strike>add leg-by-leg</strike> add the chain map that isn't formally inverted. Isomorphisms in the derived category are tricky to pin down. Any representative chain map of an isomorphism must be a quasi-isomorphism, but in general maps don't have to be representable like this. Between two bounded above complexes of projectives or two bounded below complexes of injectives, an isomorphism in the derived category lifts to a chain homotopy equivalence of complexes (a unique lift up to chain homotopy). If you only care about bounded above/below complexes you can think of the derived category as *exactly* the homotopy category of bounded above/below complexes of projectives/injectives.

For your final question, take $f$ to be a morphism between complexes each concentrated in a single degree. These complexes will have homology only in different degrees, so automatically $H^n(f) = 0$ for all $n$. Given modules $M, N$, a morphism $M[0] \to N[k]$ in the derived category can be represented as a span $M[0] \leftarrow P \to N[k]$ where $P$ is a projective resolution of $M$, and this will be nonzero iff $P \to N[k]$ is nonzero in the derived category (and since $P$ is a bounded above complex of projectives, this map has an underlying chain map and it's zero in the derived category iff the chain map is nullhomotopic). A chain map $P \to N[k]$ is the same thing as a map $P_k \to N$, so we're looking for elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(P_k, N)$ which are not null homotopic as maps $P \to N[k]$. But by definition $\operatorname{Ext}^k(M, N)$ is a subquotient of $\operatorname{Hom}(P_k, N)$, and one may check that a degree $k$ cocycle of the cochain complex complex $\operatorname{Hom}(P, N)$ is nullhomotopic as a chain map $P \to N[k]$ iff it is a boundary of this complex. So any nonzero class in an $\operatorname{Ext}$ group gives a map in the derived category like you were asking for, and a projective resolution tells you how to write down that map as a roof.